# Using llvm-mca on NASM source file

Tags: nasm, llvm-mca

I have some assembler code in NASM format that I want to analyse using LLVM-MCA. So I need to run it through NASM to resolve the macros and produce something that LLVM-MCA can accept, but the only output options seem to be binary files rather than raw assembler. I've looked at using objdump to re-generate the raw assembler but that doesn't seem to be able to create a compatible format.

Any idea how to link these tools together?

Comment: Can you show how it incompatible?

Comment: @l4m2 I'm afraid I don't recall the details and can't easily reproduce the system I was using at the time :(